# How to change console Font size in C++ using functions of windows.h?

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to change console font size, here is the code I wrote + my try to find the bug.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE Hout=GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD fsize={8,8};
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX Font;
    GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(Hout,0,&Font);

    //My Code to check the problem...............................
    std::cout<<Font.dwFontSize.X<<' '<<Font.dwFontSize.Y;getch();
    //...........................................................

    Font.dwFontSize=fsize;
    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(Hout,0,&Font);
    std::cout<<"!Test Text!";
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The bug is that the text is not changing to desired size and when I tried to check the problem by writing checking code, the output was,
`0 0`
I cannot understand anything, maybe I am missing something.
I need Help with that b'cuz I did all this topic of HANDLES and windows-functions by myself with little help of internet.

Comment: @IInspectable doesn't the GetCurrentConleont initaliszes this structure ?

Comment: If you check return code and GetLastError() you'll certainly obtain error 87, invalid parameter.   Be aware that you're only allowed to use fixed fonts within a predetermined set of allowed size.

Comment: @Christophe: What about `cbSize`?

Comment: I think that the function `GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(Hout,0,&Font);` initilizes Font with required values also i read in Microsoft website about the return values, they are 0 in both cases.

Comment: @Christophe yes I am aware and I am using one of them

Comment: @IInspectable +1 !!!  Incredible ! It works after setting it to sizeof(Font) !  I let you the honour of writig the answer and I'll immediatly upvote !

Comment: @IInspectable https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Christophe please write clearly what you want to say, I can't understand clearly.

Comment: Before the `GetCurrentConsoleFontEx()` you just have to insert the statement `Font.cbSize = sizeof(Font);` and it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most structures in the Windows API contain a size member as their first member (e.g. [OPENFILENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839.aspx)). This member must be initialized by the application. The [CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682069.aspx) is no exception.

To retrieve a `CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX` structure for the currently selected font use the following code:

```
HANDLE Hout = ::GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX Font = { sizeof( Font ) };
::GetCurrentConsoleFontEx( Hout, FALSE, &Font );
```

This zero initializes the `CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX` structure and sets the first member to `sizeof( Font )`. Checking return values is mandatory. Had you done so, the call to `GetCurrentConsoleFontEx` would have returned `0`, and `GetLastError` reported a value of 87 (ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER: The parameter is incorrect.).

Comment: Why would you use `scope resolution operator` before all these functions ?

Comment: Since the Windows API predominantly exposes a C interface, all functions live in the global namespace. Using the scope resolution operator helps disambiguate between the Windows API and colliding functions defined at namespace scope.

Comment: @Mukul: C++ doesn't perform lookup at runtime. All symbols are resolved at compile and link time. Whether you use explicit scope resolution or not doesn't have any effect on the generated object code. This is purely to prevent programming errors and serves as documentation.